# Julian Day Regex Without Leading Zeros

Tags: javascript, regex, julian-date

I am really struggling with creating a Reg Ex for Julian Day that does not allow leading zeros.

I am using it for Input Validation using JavaScript Reg Ex.  It needs to match 1 through 366.

Example Matches:

- 1
- 99
- 366
- 159

Example Match Failures:

- 01
- 001
- 099
- 367
- 999
- 0

I tried this on regex101:

> ^[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-5][0-9]|36[0-6]$

But for I am not getting the optional parts down right.  So when I put in 266, I get a match on 2 and 66.  (This issue is translating to my [input validation control](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).)

I thought about trying to use `+` for one or more, but I need to not allow leading zeros, so that does not work.

I have read the [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) on asking a RegEx question and tried to follow it, but if I missed something, please let me know and I will update my question.

Comment: Try [`^(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-6])$`](https://regex101.com/r/Uc24Ao/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Works perfectly.  Post as an answer and I will accept.  Also, if you could explain what the ?: and parens did to fix it I would love it.  (If not I will figure it out.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issues are two: 1) the alternatives should have been grouped so that `^` and `$` anchors could be applied to all of them, 2) the `[1-3][0-5][0-9]` part did not match `160` to `199` and `260` to `299`, this part should have been split into two separate branches, `[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9]`.

You may use

```
^(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-6])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uc24Ao/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - group of alternatives:

  - `[1-9]`  - 1 to 9
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9][0-9]`  - `10` to `99`
  - `|` - or
  - `[12][0-9]{2}` - `100` to `299`
  - `|`  - or
  - `3[0-5][0-9]` - `300` to `359`
  - `|` - or
  - `36[0-6]` - `360` to `366`
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `$` - and the end of the string.